# C++ Compare first and second element for all pairs in container

Tags: c++, vector, compare, similarity, std-pair

I have vector of pair like this:

```
std::vector < std::pair < int /*Val1*/, int /*Val2*/ > > myVector;
```

What is the efficient way to compare for each pair in 'myVector' first and second element of pair (Val1 and Val2) are same or not.

The only way I could think of is -

```
bool IsFirstAndSecondSame(vector<pair<T, T>> myVector)
{
    for(auto valuePair : myVector)
    {
       if(valuePair.first != valuePair.second)
           return false'
    }
    return true;
}
```

Although in example I have used pair of integers, the question is about any pair having first and second element of same type.

Comment: `vector> myVector` ??? - You cannot get help with way you asked this question, the code doesn't make any sense. What is `cosnt` in C++? ... Check your spellings. Put good effort in asking... And you will get speedy answers. Post a valid code snippet. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use `std::all_of` and a suitable function.

Answer (score 1):

> Although in example I have used pair of integers, the question is about any pair having first and second element of same type.

You're probably asking about using a templated function like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool IsFirstAndSecondSame(const vector<pair<T, T>>& myVector) // const
                                                              // ^^^^^
                                                              // makes no sense 
                                                              // with free functions
{
    for(const auto& valuePair : myVector)
    {
       if(valuePair.first != valuePair.second)
           return false'
    }
    return true;
}
```